# how to show options in select with forms.ModelChoiceField - Django

Tags: python, django

I have this problem: I need to show in a select the data of a model, I have been working with form template to customize it, but when it comes to a select I don't know how to show the options in template it only shows '' in the options.

My model:

```
class Rol(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Active'), default=True)
    sort_order = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Sort Order'), default=0)
```

My forms:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

rols = None
rol = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=rols, initial = Rol.objects.get(pk=1))
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name','rut', 'phone', 'gender', 'rol']
    exclude = ('username',)

def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    self.rols = Rol.objects.all()
    super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['rol'].queryset = self.rols
```

My HTML:

```
<tr>
                        <td class="table-text typo-grey"><label class="float-left">Rol</label></td>
                        <td class="rol centered">
                          <div class="ui input">
                            <select type="mail" id="id_{{form.rol.html_name}}"
                              name="{{form.rol.html_name}}" maxlength="100">
                              {% for rol in form.rol %}
                              <option value="{{rol.pk}}"=>{{rol.name}}</option>
                             {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
```

If u any advice or something, please coment, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is you loop is referring looping through *rol in form.rol*, but your options are referring to *form.rol* still, not *rol*.

Even if you do that, I suspect you'll have another issue. You need to have a list of rols to cycle through - and form.rol probably isn't it.  Rols are a separate model, so we'll need to collect that list separately. Try this in your form:

```
def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['rols'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Rols.objects.all()
    )
```

then, in your template.html

```
    {% for rol in form.rol.field.queryset %}
        <option value="{{ rol.id}}">{{rol.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: understand, but I have this form for an UpdateView so in views I used `rol_pk = form.cleaned_data.get('rol', None)` because I need the value for another model update

Comment: Ok, I do it. In the for I need to put `{% for rol in form.rol.field.queryset %}` so then I can access to data directly.